# Issue with zipArchive::close() returning false

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

So `zipArhive::` is returning `false`, I have tried the `getStringStatus` and it is returning "no error" so i'm stuck on what to do...

```
$fp = fopen($filePath.$fileName, 'w');
$xml = $carXML->asXML();

$zipFileName = date('dmY')."-ebay.zip";

$zip = new ZipArchive();

$r= file_exists($filePath.$fileName);
var_dump($r);
$r = $zip->open($zipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE);
var_dump($r);

$r = $zip->addFile($filePath.$fileName);
var_dump($r);

$r = $zip->getStatusString();
var_dump($r);

$r = $zip->close();
var_dump($r);

fputs ($fp, $xml);
fclose($fp);
```

> Results:bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) string(8) "No error" bool(false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're opening a file for writing but haven't created it by the time you add it to the zip archive. What happens if you create the `$fp` file (and close it) before trying to add it to the ZipArchive?

```
<?php 

$xmlFileName = $filePath.$fileName;
$fp = fopen($xmlFileName, 'w');
$xml = $carXML->asXML();
fputs ($fp, $xml);
fclose($fp);

$zipFileName = date('dmY')."-ebay.zip";

$zip = new ZipArchive();

$r = $zip->open($zipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE);
$r = $zip->addFile($xmlFileName);
$r = $zip->close();

var_dump($r);
```

Comment: I got: `bool(false) `

Comment: Ok, I found the issue, it was to do with the $zipFileName not having the complete path therefore not going to the correct place on the server. But now, in the zip file I have var/www/etc/etc/etc/etc do you know how I can just get the single file? `$zip->open($filePath.$zipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE);`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your new problem. Since you've solve the issue you asked about, perhaps it's best asked as a new question, or update this one.

Comment: yeah will do, thank you for helping :), But I do believe part of the issue was the file opening and closing, so i'll reward you for that ;)